Camera not showing up when using ZXing.Net.Maui in a Native embedded .NET MAUI project
I'm trying to integrate ZXing.Net.Maui into a simple .NET MAUI project(converted from Xamarin.Android) that I created from scratch. The project targets net8.0-android and only contains four files. However, the camera is not showing up when I run the app. If I replace the CameraBarcodeReaderView with a simple label, it shows up as expected.
Here's the relevant code:
MainActivity.cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Embedding;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;

namespace ZXingMauiNativeEmbedding.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        MauiContext mauiContext;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder.UseMauiEmbedding<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application>().UseBarcodeReader();
            var mauiApp = builder.Build();
            mauiContext = new MauiContext(mauiApp.Services, this);
            var myMauiPage = new MainPage();
            var containerView = myMauiPage.ToContainerView(mauiContext);
            SetContentView(containerView);
        }
    }

MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.MAUI.Controls"
             x:Class="ZXingMauiNativeEmbedding.Droid.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30,0" Spacing="25" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="barcodeReader" BarcodesDetected="BarcodesDetected" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

MainPage.xaml.cs
using ZXing.Net.Maui;

namespace ZXingMauiNativeEmbedding.Droid
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            barcodeReader.Options = new BarcodeReaderOptions
            {
                Formats = BarcodeFormats.All,
                AutoRotate = true,
                Multiple = false
            };
            barcodeReader.CameraLocation = CameraLocation.Front;
        }

        public void BarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
        {
            var first = e.Results?.FirstOrDefault();
            if (first is null)
                return;

            Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Barcode Detected", first.Value, "OK");
            });
        }
    }
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>  

I have already added the camera permission to the AndroidManifest.xml, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What am I missing? How can I get the camera to show up when using ZXing.Net.Maui in a Native embedded .NET MAUI project? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Please find the github link here: https://github.com/nandhakishore92/ZXingMauiNativeEmbedding

I suspect you’re missing UseBarcodeReader() in your MauiProgram.cs

But I don't have a MauiProgram.cs file, as my project is converted from Xamarin.Android to .NET MAUI. I wanted to keep my changes minimal and functional, I only changed what was necessary. Everything else in my app works fine except for the scanning part. The code I have posted in this question is a sample app that only contains the scanning part. And please note that I have already added UseBarcodeReader() in my MainActivity class's OnCreate method.
